# Ошибка js: SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier

Tags: javascript

Консоль ругается на объявление класса в .js файле.
Код на который ссылается ошибка:

```
class Foo {
```

Сама ошибка:

> SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier

Comment: что за консоль?

Comment: Браузерная консоль

Comment: Что за барузер?

Comment: И поддерживает ли ваш браузер ES2015?)

Comment: Пробовал Firefox и Chrome. В Chrome тоже выдается ошибка, только немного иная: Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: @Jhony а вы вообще с какой целью хотите использовать именно `class`?

Comment: @Jhony, TL;DR: ваш браузер не поддерживает ES2015

Comment: @DmitriySimushev не _полностью_ поддерживает ES2015

Comment: @Grundy, да, конечно. но это уже детали)